# Bottleneck when running Linux from USB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, nas

I have a NAS device with two 3.5 HDD disks and an internal 500mb flash drive for the bootloader. As the NAS is in the same room as I sleep and to avoid wear on the disks, I dont want to have the operating system on one of the spinning HDDs. I was thinking to rather install it either on a USB thumb drive or on an external SSD. The NAS has a USB 3.0 port.
Now I was wondering how fast that system would be. I understand, that the operating system is loaded at start from the thumb drive and that the speed limit then is probably the USB connection. As the NAS preferably never reboots I dont care about boot time. But how is the speed once the system is booted. Will it be the same as if the OS is installed on an internal disk, or would it be significantly slower? And what is the bottleneck? The speed of the USB drive, the USB port or the ram on the system?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: What does the NAS do except backup and serving files? Updates of course, but that won't be the problem. Try it! And use a good USB stick, not the cheapest. Make sure it performs well on speed, look for reviews on Amazon or elsewhere.

Comment: Good question. I should have been more precise. I intent to run Owncloud on it and daily rsync backups of my Laptop. So it will also be a home server.

Comment: You will need plenty of main memory to avoid swapping to the USB, which will rapidly reach the write cycle limit in the swap area.

Comment: You want to run Owncloud. The device may be sold as a NAS, it may be called a NAS, but without enough RAM it won't run Owncloud from memory. You could set the swap to write to the HDD, but I don't know how often that will cause the disks to startup during night. How about using a small external SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NAS will typically not access the OS disk at all, after ist has completed the startup - so you won't see a difference.

That said, you might want to take care, if, where and when it writes logfiles: Log write load can be a PITA with USB.